# Go for a specific object in array list in Java?

Tags: java, android, search, arraylist

I have a Array list which contains Objects of Restaurants

```
ArrayList<Restaurants> array_sort = new ArrayList<Restaurants>();
```

Restaurant object is contain its name and Id. Beside of that there is a Alphabetical Index. I need to go for the specific letter in the array when user click on the index letter. This image will give you a good idea.

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an ArrayList for this task is not a good idea because it doesn't provide any efficient solution to your problem. I'd suggest to use a `TreeMap<String,Resturant>`. The good thing of the TreeMap is that it has the method

```
public NavigableMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey,
                            boolean fromInclusive,
                            K toKey,
                            boolean toInclusive)
```

which returns a portion of the map that contains just the items you need for the specific letter, already sorted. This submap is backed by the full one so it's a light weight object.

You can easily do something like `subMap("a", true, "b", false)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate the items in each of the letters before that letter and then use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest  option can be to have a map also mapping display indices to list of restaurant objects.